# H2 database: NULL not allowed for column "ID" when inserting record using jdbcTemplate

Tags: hibernate, h2

I use hibernate's hbm2ddl to generate schema automatically. Here is my domain:

```
@Entity
public class Reader {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  Long id;

  @Column(nullable=false,unique=true)
  String name;

  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  Gender gender;

  int age;

  Date registeredDate = new Date();

// getter and setter ...
}
```

When I using hibernate to save a `reader`, it works fine as expected as it generats a id to the `reader` . However when I use jdbcTemplate to insert a record with pure SQL, it report an error:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: StatementCallback; 
SQL [insert into reader(name,gender,age) values('Lily','FEMALE',21)]; 
NULL not allowed for column "ID"; 
    SQL statement:insert into reader(name,gender,age) values('Lily','FEMALE',21) [23502-192]; 
nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: NULL not allowed for column "ID"; 
    SQL statement:  insert into reader(name,gender,age) values('Lily','FEMALE',21) [23502-192]
```

How to solve this?

1. I debug to find that the DDL of hb2ddl generated is `create table Book (id bigint not null, author varchar(255), name varchar(255), price double not null, type varchar(255), primary key (id))`. It seems that the hiberate handle the id stratege in its own way but how?
2. The `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)` should generate `auto increment` in the statement of the DDL but I didn't find that. Did I miss it?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Try to use `strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY` instead of the `strategy=GenerationType.AUTO`

Also could be wrong hibernate.dialect
Try the

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

Comment: Thanks. When I change to the `strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY`, It works. And the DDL clause now changed to `create table Reader (id bigint generated by default as identity, age integer not null, gender varchar(255), name varchar(255) not null, registeredDate timestamp, primary key (id))`. So what the diffence between `IDENTITY` and `AUTO` here?

Comment: **IDENTITY** Indicates that the persistence provider must assign primary keys for the entity using a database identity column. **AUTO** Indicates that the persistence provider should pick an appropriate strategy for the particular database. The<code>AUTO</code> generation strategy may expect a database resource to exist, or it may attempt to create one. A vendor may provide documentation on how to create such resources in the event that it does not support schema generation or cannot create the schema resource at runtime.

Comment: I was also facing the same problem with the spring boot : 3.1.3, hibernate-core: 6.2.7 and H2 2.1.214 combination with strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY. For me strategy=GenerationType.AUTO worked as it created sequence in H2 DB and started using it for generating ids. Just keeping this info here if someone faces same challenge :-)

Answer (score 22):

If you're using H2 dependency version: "**2.0.202**" or higher, those other 2 aproaches might work.

1: Use H2 version: "**1.4.200**" ('com.h2database:h2:1.4.200')

2: Append "**;MODE=LEGACY**" to the JDBC url (`test case -> jdbc:h2:mem:test;MODE=LEGACY`)

Comment: Thanks, [method 2](https://github.com/tarent/timestamp-utc/commit/a42b21e0665e7c7d86d3f4b341b78c7497570cce) indeed worked! So apparently, the H2 “security” update broke its functionality?

Comment: Thank you! I faced this after upgrading from version **1.4.200** to version **2.1.210**. You solution worked for me.

Comment: Option 2 worked for me too. due to vulnerability in 1.4.200 version, I had to upgrade to latest version and unit test were breaking.

Comment: Related H2 issue on GitHub "Upgrade H2 version 2.0.204 from 1.4.200": https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/3325

Answer (score 15):

Hibernate 5.2.x (Spring Boot 2.x) change default strategy for sequences, if DB supported one. So, with `strategy=GenerationType.AUTO`, `hibernate_sequence` is created, but `id` is not autoincremented, based on this sequence, as must be:

```
create table users (id integer not null, ...)
```

instead of

```
create table table_name(id int default hibernate_sequence.nextval primary key, ...);
```

(see [HHH-13268](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-13268)). There are several solutions:

- change `@GeneratedValue` to `strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY`
- set `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=false` (spring-boot alias `spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings`)
- insert with nextval: `INSERT INTO TABLE(ID, ...) VALUES (hibernate_sequence.nextval, ...)`

Answer (score 7):

This has been resolved in Hibernate 5.6.5 (Spring Boot 2.6.4), so that H2 version 2.0.202 (or higher) works again.

See https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/pull/4524 for reference.