# ManyToMany RelationShip NULL not allowed for column

Tags: java, spring, jpa, many-to-many

I am trying to make a `@ManyToMany` relationship between two entities.

**Post** Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Post")
public class Post {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "post_label", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "POST_ID", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "LABEL_ID", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    List<Label> labels = new ArrayList<Label>() ;

    // getters and setters

}
```

And **Label** Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Label")
public class Label{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    long id;

    String name;

    String color;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "labels")
    List<Post> posts = new ArrayList<Post>() ;

    // getters and setters.

}
```

When I try to save a `Post`, appears this error:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: NULL not allowed for column "LABEL_ID"; SQL statement:
insert into noticia (id, date, description, facebookid, postedonfacebook, postedonfake, publishdate, subtitle, title, type, visitorscount) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [23502-194]
```

And similar error when I try to save a `Label`:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: NULL not allowed for column "NOTICIA_ID"; SQL statement:
insert into label (id, color, name) values (null, ?, ?) [23502-194]
```

Point 1: I tried to save a `Post` without adding no `Label` (same error).
         I tried to save a `Label` without adding no `Post` (same error)

Point 2: I tried to save a `Post` adding `Label` (same error).
         I tried to save a `Label` adding `Post` (same error)

Comment: suppose you try to use `strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY` instead of the `strategy=GenerationType.AUTO`

Comment: it doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

Your mapping looks fine.

The problem could be in the way you are saving your entities.

Try the following code to persist your `Post` and its `Label` child  entities.

```
Post post = new Post();

List<Label> labels = new ArrayList<>();
Label firstLabel = new Label();
firstLabel.setColor("MAROON");
firstLabel.setName("MAROONIFIED");
labels.add(firstLabel);

Label secondLabel = new Label();
secondLabel.setColor("BLUE");
secondLabel.setName("BLUEFIED");
labels.add(secondLabel);

post.setLabels(labels);

postRepository.save(post);
```

Also check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39094649/h2-database-null-not-allowed-for-column-id-when-inserting-record-using-jdbcte) answer for `h2` specific problem.

Comment: Is it possible to save a `post` without adding `labels`?